# Как закрепить изменённый текст в textview

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

При нажатии кнопки я изменяю textview с помощью .setText(), но при выходе из приложения текст становится изначальным, как мне закрепить новый текст для textview?

Comment: сохранить в SharedPreferences, например.

Answer (score 2):

Важно понимать, что вся работа с приложением происходит в оперативной памяти, а не постоянной и любые изменения сделанные в программе при закрытии приложения будут стираться. Для сохранения данных можно использовать несколько способов, которые пользуются популярностью в Android:

- Сохранение в БД (используется для сложных структур данных)
- Сохранение в файл
- Сохранение в SharedPreferences: специальное хранилище в виде файла в Android для хранения пар "ключ-значение"

Вы можете использовать любой из выше описанных способов, но я рекомендую SharePreferences. 
[Здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) очень подробно описано как реализовывать сохранение в SharedPreferences как раз для Вашего случая.